Korean manhwa where the female MC wakes up in a capsule, and she finds out she's the only female left after a disease killed all women
I only read the first chapter and I lost it

The main character is a teenage female. She wakes up in a capsule and I think she finds a video that explains what happened to her and why she's there:
There was a disease (I think) that made women give birth to only males and no females. That disease killed all women and I think that they became extinct (I'm not sure as I only read the first chapter, and that was 3 years ago).
She wakes up in a capsule many years after that.
A scientist or a doctor put her in the capsule to protect her from the disease.
I think she's the only female left and the doctor explains to her that she has to hide from the men because if they found out about her they will experiment on her or sell her to rich men and she'll become a breeding machine.
She runs out of the room she was in and goes outside and finds 2 people, a man and one who seems like a woman but this woman is transgender, and when they see her they think that she's also transgender. I think that one of them (the trans woman) touched her breast and compliments her on looking and feeling like a real female.
She runs away from these two, and they go after her. (I think that they wanted to have s*x with her, or to see how good was her operation down there and tell them the doctor that operated on her.)
She escapes to an all boys high school and she finds a student there. He figures out that she's a real female and hides her from the others and protects her.
The art drawing of this manhwa is the same like the manhwa "My Boyfriend is a Vampire" like this:

 

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?

@sakinadesu - Please merge your new account with the one you used to post this question by following the instructions provided here. Once the accounts are merged, you'll regain the ability to post comments in this thread, edit this question without approval from other users, and mark an answer as accepted, if one is posted.

Did you read an online version or was it a physical copy.

Is this The Only Girl...?

The world has became a place dominated by males. Women are virtually extinct with their number-count in the hundreds and the youngest of the them in her forties. It has been long accepted that a wife, being a gender so rare, can have multiple husbands. Sex change to satisfy sexual desire is a growing phenomenon, although is still looked down upon by society. In such a disordered place where she is the only girl, Ho Su awakens.

In the year 2010, strange green light from the Sun mutates the X chromosomes of almost all human females on the planet. Girls and women aged ten or above survive, but the rest die, including girls born from that point forward.
It's determined that the human race will go extinct unless a human female can be found with a normal X chromosome and the one girl found to have that is Kang Ho Soo, the teenage daughter of a Korean scientist. Realising that knowledge of her existence could spark a civil or international war, her father and some other scientists decide to place her in suspended animation for 30 years, by which time they hope that things will have settled down.



In the year 2042, Ho Soo wakes up from suspended animation and is greeted by a young male scientist who tries to explain the situation to her. She doesn't believe him and flees the building, only to run into a group of four young men who think she's a transwoman and begin sexually assaulting her. Another young man comes along and beats the four men up, saving her and telling her to go back. Then the young scientist catches up to her and brings her back to the building she woke up in.
With the help of a letter left by her now-deceased father, he manages to convince her that he was telling her the truth and she gets a haircut and starts dressing like a boy so that she can pass as one for her own safety. She also enrols at an all-boys school to complete her education. Some of the students at the school are transwomen.




Pretty sure this IS the title the OP was looking for. (Everything matches perfectly with the OP description) Looks like its also known as "GIRL (Mi-Ri HWANG)" it appears there were 16 chapters translated into English. I wasn't able to find out if there were more chapters released in the original Korean language.  The last Chapter translated to English was released 5 years ago.
